# Related records in HTML email template

Tags: email-template

I have a email alert which fires on contact record edit.

Is it possible to display related records name in HTML email template? I know it can be displayed using VF email template, but is a there a workaround in HTML email template.

Answer (score 0):

While creating an HTML email template you have option to merge the fields. Where you can bind the value for this. [image]

Comment: If I am having multiple related records, Will it be displaying all those records name even I mention it once like {!relationshipname.fieldname}